# Is this question about the Google Maps API off topic?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, scope

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54846766/google-maps-api-not-producing-expected-results) about the Google Maps API. It took time carefully to explain the problem, what I was getting and what I expected. I included all relevant code. But the question now has a down- and a close-vote (with the "lacks MCVE" off-topic reason).

I don't see how this is off-topic. There are two possible reasons for my problem:

1. There's a problem with my code. In that case someone can notice the problem and point it out. That's perfectly on topic.
2. I'm misunderstanding the Google Maps API in some way. In that case someone who knows the API well can explain that. The Google Maps API is just another programming tool, this is no different from asking questions about how Angular or some other library works.

Is there something I'm missing, or is the close vote not really legitimate?

Comment: The close-vote is for the reason “Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a _specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).”.

Comment: @Xufox But I included all of that. The code in the question is everything you need to reproduce the problem.

Comment: But it's a typo; how useful is a typo going to be in the future?

Comment: @fbueckert It turned out to be a typo. Should I never ask any question in case the problem turns out to have been a typo?

Comment: No, but should we keep questions that are typos?  Are they going to be useful for anyone at all in the future?

Comment: @JackM If the typo is something common that people will hit, and if you can edit the question in such a way that it's easy to find for someone with your same issue, then it can be useful for future readers. But as the question stands, it doesn't seem like other users will make the same typo, and if they did, it would be really hard to find your question. The votes are used to judge utility for future users. You've received the help you needed, which is good, but since the question is unlikely to help future readers, that's likely why the down and close votes are appearing.

Comment: @DavyM I think there's some confusion here. I first posted this meta question before having posted my own answer. The down- and close-vote predates my answer to the question.

Comment: Which is fine; we're building a repository to withstand the test of time.  There's a close reason specifically for typo-questions, because they can't withstand that test.  They're just not useful to anyone else.  A single close vote and downvote aren't really worth mentioning; the question is whether or not the question should be closed or not.

Comment: @fbueckert The point is, the close-vote was made before it was known that the problem was a typo, so clearly that wasn't the issue. This meta question was originally about understanding why that close-vote was made, to find out if it was actually in line with site policy, and if so what was wrong with the question, so I can avoid asking such questions here in future.

Answer (score 7):

The question wasn't closed. There was a single close vote. Raising a meta-question for a single close vote is a bit too much, IMO.

We can't tell you why the user that chose that close reason did so. We do not know why. But in all likelyhood it was because they didn't notice your typo. Without the typo, your code doesn't have the issue you mentioned in the question, and as such the user probably thought something along the lines of "there is no problem evidenced by the presented code". But again, this is just speculation.

The subject matter of the question is ok, but the actual question is not worth keeping around.

We all have this kind of problem now and then, no shame in that. But I believe it is probably better to delete the question instead of self-answering. It's not useful for future visitors. Users will have this kind of trouble with very using different programming languages, libraries, and APIs. It's simply not searchable, since if you knew that the problem with your code was a typo, you wouldn't be searching for a solution but actually fixing the typo.

Finally, discussing down votes is not really worth anyone's time. A single down vote, even less.